# Using jquery with expiry dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I please get any help finishing this code I did for my website. I'm using jquery and what this code does is its checking the recert date (expiry date) of an application first before a customer can re-apply again, so basically they can only re-apply within 4 weeks of their current application expiry date.

e.g. if a person application expires Aug 31 2016 that means they can only re-apply from Aug 3 2016 to Aug 31 2016 with 4 weeks to be exact. An application last for 3 years.

I provided my code and its working but I don't know if this is the right conditions and all it does is just hide the apply button if expiry date is still not up.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var current = new Date();
    var expiry = new Date($("#mcs_nextrecertdate").val());

    if(current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()){
        $("#NextButton").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#NextButton").hide();
    }
```

EDIT: Im testing the codes I receive from the answers based on these dates first can re-apply with 27 august 2016 and the second is a date that can't re-apply yet 20 July 2019

Comment: What is the value format of `<input id="mcs_nextrecertdate"  />`

Comment: Seems OK on the surface. Consider turning this into a snippet to show the whole thing. Also, make sure your validation is not entirely client-side - remember you can never trust your users!

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI the value format of the recert dates is 22 July 2016.

Comment: thus, u don't have pb  with date format.. Congrats & see my answer for best practices

Comment: @Owen thanks for your comment. The validations for this doesn't matter at the moment because the form is a read-only so they won't be be able to add nor edit anything in their record. The re-apply button would only show up if their expiry date is up and it will throw in an alert as well saying "This Application must be recertified within 4 weeks from recert date"

Comment: @Owen I know what you mean now in terms of validating Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I still think my code only shows the re-apply button on the date of expiry not the actual 4 weeks within expiry date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your question and explanation of your problem, I'd like to point out a few observations I've made

#### 1. Date validation

```
var expiry = new Date($("#mcs_nextrecertdate").val());
```

Whatever `#mcs_nextrecertdate` is, I'll assume you've already made sure that this "input" element's value is correctly formatted. Otherwise you'll get a JS script error and the whole thing will break

#### 2. Incorrect logic

Based on your explanation, a user can only re-certify WITHIN 4 weeks of the current application's expiry date. I'll assume that `#NextButton` is a submit button that triggers the new application. Based on that, this expression is wrong...

```
if(current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()){...}
```

because you're telling your app to allow users to apply for a certification **AFTER** the current application has expired, **NOT WITHIN 4 weeks** after expiration, in other words, users can ONLY re-apply after they're application expired...not before.

#### 3. Server validation

This is just an assumption. I'll also assume this "client-side logic" is just to offer a good user experience of your app and that you are running proper server-side validation otherwise advanced users like me can easily bypass client-side validation, cheat/hack these "constraints" and even bring your application data to an inconsistent state.

## Correct Logic

In order to make sure users can re-apply **within 4 weeks prior to the current expiry date** you need to do the following...

```
var now = new Date();
var expiry = new Date($("#mcs_nextrecertdate").val());//assuming this has a valid date
var startValidAppDate = new Date($("#mcs_nextrecertdate").val());

//set valid application dates
startValidAppDate.setTime(expiry.getTime() - (7 * 4 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));//4 weeks to milliseconds

if(now < expiry && now > startValidAppDate){
     //ok to apply
     $("#NextButton").show();
}
```

Again, ALWAYS make sure you have strong validation on the server. Here's a working snipper...

```js
$(function(){
        $('#txtExpiryDateParent').datetimepicker({
                format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
            });
  
      $("a").click(function(){
          var now = new Date();
          var expiry = new Date($("#txtExpiryDate").val());
          var startValidAppDate = new Date($("#txtExpiryDate").val());

          //set valid application dates
          startValidAppDate.setTime(expiry.getTime() - (7 * 4 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));//4 weeks to milliseconds

          if(now < expiry && now > startValidAppDate){
              $(".info.bg-success").show();
              $(".info.bg-error").hide();
          }
        else{
              $(".info.bg-success").hide();
              $(".info.bg-error").show();
          }
        });
  });
```

```css
form{
  background-color:#eee;
  max-width:500px;
  padding:30px;
  margin:30px;  
  }

.info{
  padding:20px;
  border-radius:3px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  display:none;
  }
.bg-success{
  background-color:#5cb85c !important;
  }
.bg-error{
  background-color:#d9534f !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />


<form class="center-block">
   <div class="info bg-success">You're good to re-certify</div>
   <div class="info bg-error">You can't certify right now</div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtExpiryDate">Expiry Date</label>
            <div class='input-group date' id='txtExpiryDateParent'>
                <input id="txtExpiryDate" type='text' name="ExpiryDate" class="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Expiry date..."  />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0)">Validate</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Leo for your feedback but this doesn't work, now it shows the re-apply button.

Comment: @Ejay I'm not sure what you mean by "DOESN't WORK", I've provided a code snippet BASED On your required logic to prove that fact

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear Leo. yes your logic works but when I tried to put out the new code it seems its just showing the re-apply button regardless what the expiry date is so I'm still working on it and thanks a lot for the fully detail answer you gave

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly now. Thank you so much for your effort and you even provided some really great snippet. I apologies earlier if I made any misunderstandings the thing is I had to apply these to a custom javascript inside a portal that's why it took me a bit to do this as I am laso using SAGE Crm especially this bit 'if(now < expiry && now > startValidAppDate){' i forgot to put getTime() next to them but yeah I tested it all with some future, old, current and upcoming dates and your solution works now so thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices in **client-side** is to `remove` your element NOT hide it .

```
if(current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()){
    $("#NextButton").show();
}
else {
    $("#NextButton").remove();
}
```

Ans Best Practices in **server-side** are to check expiration date there and render  HTML without `#NextButton` element.

Comment: I see thanks for answering but still not sure whether my condition is correct

Comment: condtion should be the opposite

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, always do testing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var current = new Date();
//var expiry = new Date("August 1, 2014");
var expiry = new Date("August 13, 2017");

if(current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()){
    $("#NextButton").show();
}
else {
    $("#NextButton").hide();
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but expiry dates are random and should be apply to every customer its not just one specific expiry date